# Android Development related to Xml layouts

Tags: android

I have made a layout for an app,it runs fine on my phone but when I use a smaller size phone to run it the user interface changes and is not in accordance.For example the buttons go out of screen or their order of placement changes.What should I do?

Comment: Show screenshot and xml code please.

Comment: use RelativeLayout and place views(i.e. buttons) according to user specification.

Comment: This is exactly why Android development is quite tricky. When creating your xml layout you have to foresee that it can be displayed on multiple screens. Smaller and larger.

Comment: Learn about  Relativelayout, linearlayout  it may helpfull. Also be aware of WrapContent,MatchParent

Answer (score 1):

you have to develop different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for small, medium, high, and extra high density screens.

For layouts

```
res/layout/mainactivity.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/mainactivity.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/mainactivity.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/mainactivity.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/mainactivity.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

For drawables

```
res/drawable-mdpi/ic_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/ic_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_icon.png
```

put following code in the Manifest

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
          android:normalScreens="true" 
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:xlargeScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Kindly look at the following links for more reference

[https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html -> **Diff Screen Size**](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

[https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html -> **Diff Screen Supports**](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

Few tips for single layout:

- Design your views relatively(Check Relative-Layout and Frame-Layout) .
- Take the advantage of weight(Check Linear Layout).
- Use scroll view if your layout height is big.

For Ex: If you want to put some buttons(for say 2) on the bottom of the screen just use **RelativeLayout** as parent and inside that **LinearLayout** with `alignparentbotton=true` after that you can define buttons, you also can use weight on buttons to equally align horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way to support different screen sizes. You need to create layout folders depending on screen sizes. (like layout-normal, layout-large, etc). Place your xml layout files in each folders. Don't use hard dp/sp  values.

Go through 
[Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Use weights inside Layouts to adjust the views properly.
It is the most reliable way to do it.